# Tableau - Map is Reversed

Tags: tableau-api

Has anyone had issues with Tableau Maps displaying backwards? I believe the only workaround for this would be to have my own custom background image and supply the min/max lat/lon.

My data is outlined as the following, and is plotted using the lat/lon in the data.

```html
City | Latitude_DC | Longitude_DC
```

[image: Tableau Map Reversed]

Comment: From the screenshot I can see you have the "pin" on, which means your map/view is in a custom position. If you reset the axes, do you get the same view? Also, you can simply try to position the map to the correct "order" by using the mouse and scrolling left/right.

Comment: The image in the question doesn't look backwards.

Comment: It's not backwards, I just want it to be more relative to the US. ie, having the US on the left. If I reset the axis it remains exactly as seen in the screenshot.

Comment: Are you sure you can't move the map using the mouse and then pin your view? I'm trying this in my Tableau client and it works.

Comment: I am able to move the map, but the second I click pin it resets the axis and returns to the view displayed in the Screenshot. The only workaround I've found is to move the screen, then just save without pinning it. That work's fine but obviously not desired. 

I wish I could provide the worksheet but can't provide the data needed.

Comment: @JeffBeagley The best option so far for me is to fix the map and uncheck "Show View Toolbar" from map options so that users cannot reset the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *not-so-evident* and *not-the-best* solution that pops to mind is the one provided in the comments, simply dragging/moving the map using the mouse and publishing the dashboard without resetting the axis.

In your dashboard you can even create a small floating text-box alerting people **to not pin the map** if it's something you might be concerned.

I'm not sure about how Tableau's algorithm works to decide that the best map position for your data is putting the United States at right, and I don't think there's a real fix for that (if it's considered a bug to be fixed).

Comment: Yup I'd have to agree. Thanks for looking into it!

Really not sure if it's a data issue or not, If you use custom background images you can supply the min/max dimensions or lat/long but not on their default map.